# Azure python function app cant load azure-identity module

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-identity

I have built an azure python function app which used to run fine. However it now is unable to load the azure-identity module without timing out. It will not crash, but will simply never make it past any line such as `from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential`. After 5 minutes the function times out. Does anyone have any idea what could cause this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced the same in my environment with below steps:

- Created Python Azure function App with the below code:

```py
import azure.functions as func
import logging
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

app = func.FunctionApp()
container_name = "testkp" 
blob_name = "Blob.txt" 
@app.route(route="http_trigger", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

  # Use DefaultAzureCredential to authenticate
    credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

    # Initializing BlobServiceClient with DefaultAzureCredential
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url="https://<storage_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net", credential=credential)

    # Access a container
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)

    # Access a blob
    blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob_name)
    blob_content = blob_client.download_blob().content_as_text()

    return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}! Blob Content: {blob_content}")
```

**requirements.txt:**

Add Packages required:

```
azure-functions
azure-identity
azure-storage-blob
```

- Create and activate Virtual environment with the below commands:

```
python3 -m venv .venv
.\.venv\Scripts\activate
```

[image]

- Run `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install the dependencies:

[image]

**Note:** You should have **Storage Blob Data Contributor role** assigned in your storage account.

**Portal:**

- Create a container in storage account and upload a Blob.

[image]

- Run the function with the command `func host start`:

[image]

[image]

**Response:**

[image]